# Sprite kit nodes stuttering when coming in contact

Tags: sprite-kit

I have an enemy category and a player category set up and contact detection works well between the two like it should, but when the nodes of the enemy category come in contact with each other, or the border of the screen when they enter or exit the screen, they stutter a little bit. What is the physics body property they need to not interact with anything except for there contact test bit mask.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
sprite.physicsBody.collisionBitMask = 0
```

This will make it so that only the contact events you specify will affect movement and behavior of a sprite.